# How to check success or failure of a command that is within an expect block

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have a bash code which uses expect in between to read from terminal through spawn. The code is somewhat as shown:

```
expect <{cat <<'EOD'
spawn command_whose_success_or_failure_i_want_to_know
interact
EOD
)
```

The problem is to find the success or failure of "command_whose_success_or_failure_i_want_to_know" within expect block.

Right now when I am doing :

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
blah
```

It is actually checking for expect success and not the inside command which I want to check for.
How can I do that here?
Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Lets say I put exit 42 above "interact" line of code. How will I then verify for its success or failure later?

Comment: ok, but I will need to give multiple cases in expect block. One for success and other for failure?

Answer (score 1):

You'll do this (untested):

```
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    # if your command takes > 10 seconds to complete, uncomment the next line:
    # set timeout $some_number_of_seconds_or_negative_one

    spawn command_whose_success_or_failure_i_want_to_know
    expect eof

    set result [wait]
    if {[lindex $result 2] == 0} {
        exit [lindex $result 3] ;# exit expect with the command's exit status
    } else {
        error "an operating system error occurred, errno=[lindex $result 3]"
    }
END_EXPECT
exit_status=$?

echo "the command exited with: $exit_status"
```

Comment: People very often mistakenly use interact at the end of the script when they should use expect eof.